# Как бы я объединил несколько файлов .py в один .exe

Tags: python-3.x

могли бы вы мне помочь. Чем можно конвертировать эти файлы в единый .exe, что бы все скрипты находило.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем файле `main.py` должна присутствовать строчка что-то вроде `from . input *`

Далее используйте `pyinstaller`:

`pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

Он сам упакует все зависимости (которыми и являются ваши файлы)

Comment: у меня не получилось с точечкой, делал отдельно каждый файл: from check_db.py import * и так для каждого файла, наверно можно какой цикл написать. может какой проектный файл нужен...